# Can GWT RequestFactory calls be cookie-parameterized?

Tags: java, gwt, cookies, httprequest, requestfactory

I understand that with GWT RequestFactory, server-side calls are all made to a `RequestFactoryServlet`. I'd like to write a GWT application (using RequestFactory) that looks to a cookie to determine which base URL all server-side calls are made to.

So, I'd have 3 different WAR files deployed to 3 different Tomcat instances living on 3 different physical servers, mapped to 3 different IP addresses (URLs). Each WAR would have a `RequestFactoryServlet` defined and would be capable of servicing requests from the same GWT client.

But, on the client-side, if a `widgetType` cookie has a value of `red`, I want all server-side requests to go to:

> http://red.example.com/RequestFactoryServlet#doGet

If `widgetType=blue`, then I want all server-side requests to go to:

> http://blue.example.com/RequestFactoryServlet#doGet

If `widgetType=orange`, then I want all server-side requests to go to:

> http://orange.example.com/RequestFactoryServlet#doGet

So, in summary, the client-side cookie (`widgetType`) determines which `RequestFactoryServlet` on which WAR/server/URL the HTTP requests get sent to and processed by.

**Is this possible?** If not, why and is there anything that I can do here? If it is possible, how is it possible (what code/techniques/etc do I need to utilize)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same-Origin potential issues put aside, all you need is to initialize your `RequestFactory` with a custom `RequestTransport`. The easiest is to extend [`DefaultRequestTransport`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/gwt/client/DefaultRequestTransport.html) and initialize its `setRequestUrl` depending on the cookie value.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Broyer (+1) - would the (potential) Same-Origin issues be with RequestFactory or would they exist at the browser-level (in other words, it works fine in, say, Firefox, but not allowed in certain versions of IE, etc.)? Thanks again!

Comment: At the browser-level. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy and http://caniuse.com/cors